# Find inflection points and concavity intervals of $f(x)=(x^2-1)^{(2/3)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a problem with this exercise. Look this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UDRj.jpg). I have answered two questions about it but, I could not find the way to establish the next:

- Is the function concave upward in $(1,\infty)$?
- Is $-1$ an inflection point?

Comment: I already did that... and I got the second derivate. But I could not find the arguments to establish if those questions are true or false

Comment: Using the chain rule you can find the second derivative. Set this equal to 0. Then, if the second derivative function is positive on the interval from (1,infinity) it will be concave upward, on this interval. To find the inflection point, determine where that function changes from negative to positive. If this occurs at -1, -1 is an inflection point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative#Concavity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The function concave upward in $(\sqrt3,∞)$. 
The second derivative is positive for $x>\sqrt3$
$$f''(x)=\frac{4(x^2-3)}{9(x^2-1)^{\frac43}}$$

2) There is no derivative at $x=-1$

Comment: How did you establish that $f''(x)>0$?

Comment: If $x>\sqrt3$ then $f''(x)>0$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking the first and second derivative of this polynomial and analyzing the roots of the first and second derivatives. There should be a theorem you can then use to deduce on which intervals the function is concave up or down, where it is increasing, decreasing, or neither, and as well where the inflection points are.